# Modify the visibility of a row via keyboard interaction in UWP application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

Here is my scenario. My table has fixed number of columns, say 2, and initially, it has only one visible row, but when the focus is on the last column of row 1 and the user press 'tab', row 2 will be made visible.

My problem is that I can't dynamically select the row I want to make visible because I have to specify its `x:Name` during compilation.

Below is my current work.

.xaml file

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="SP1">
        <TextBox Text="1-1"/>
        <TextBox Text="1-2" KeyDown="showNextLine"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="SP2" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBox Text="2-1"/>
        <TextBox Text="2-2"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <!--the remaining rows...-->
</StackPanel>
```

.cs file

```
private int lastRowIndex = 1;

private void showNextLine(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lastRowIndex++;
    string nextLineName = "SP" + lastRowIndex.ToString();
    nextLineName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // which causes error because nextLineName is string instead of StackPanel
}
```

Besides, my current implementation is to create 50 rows and make the last 49 invisible initially, and I am open to any method to group all the `TextBox` more systematically or flexibly.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: When you add a new column, How about the row below? Does it also add column? Or column will be added in only the row that is focused and Tabbed?

Comment: There are always fixed number of columns in each row. In this scenario, the first row has two columns, so when the second row is made visible, it also has two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of an easy way to do the first part of this (since you have 50 stack panels), but if you put all of them in a `dictionary`, then you could update them using just the key.

Here's the dictionary part done manually:

```
Dictionary<int, StackPanel> myStackPanels = new Dictionary<int, StackPanel>();
myStackPanels.Add(1, SP1);
myStackPanels.Add(2, SP2);
```

Then, here's what `ShowNextLine` would look like:

```
private void showNextLine(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lastRowIndex++;
    // Modify the StackPanel whose key is lastRowIndex;
    myStackPanels[lastRowIndex] = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: It seems perfect for me, let me try it. Besides, because I need 50 `StackPanel`, do you know any method to generate the corresponding `XAML` code efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

You could give the parent StackPanel an x:Name or keep a reference to it if you create it dynamically:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="root" Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="SP1">
        <TextBox Text="1-1"/>
        <TextBox Text="1-2" KeyDown="showNextLine"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="SP2" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBox Text="2-1"/>
        <TextBox Text="2-2"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <!--the remaining rows...-->
</StackPanel>
```

...and then get a reference to a child StackPanel using the Children property and some basic LINQ:

```
private void showNextLine(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lastRowIndex++;
    string nextLineName = "SP" + lastRowIndex.ToString();
    StackPanel child = root.Children.OfType<StackPanel>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == nextLineName);
    if (child != null)
        child.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

> How could I create a StackPanel dynamically?

Like this:

```
var sp = new StackPanel { Name = "SP3", Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal, Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed };
sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "3-1" });
var txt = new TextBlock() { Text = "3-2" };
txt.KeyDown += showNextLine;
sp.Children.Add(txt);
root.Children.Add(sp);
```

Comment: How could I create a StackPanel dynamically? I only know I can bind it during running time. Thanks for response.